# Routes that are not home route doesn't work when I host the web app

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have built a web app using flutter with GetX State management,
the app was working good, but when I hosted it on the internet all the routes doesn't work except the home route, I am using GetX Routing system but I don't what is actually the problem

to explain the problem:
when I use localhost:

- localhost:3000/: It returns the home route
- localhost:3000/terms  : It returns the terms route
- localhost:3000/john : It returns the profile of the user named john

but when I hosted it:

- domain.site/ : It returns the home route
- domain.site/terms : It returns 404
- domain.site/john : It returns 404

Thanks

Comment: Are you using named routes?

Comment: @Md.KamrulAmin Yes

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem...
I fix it with Nginx config,just to use rewrite or try to redirect the url.